# jhipster - generator-jhipster compilation from main branch

Tags: jhipster

Trying to build from source main branch.

```
git clone https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster.git --depth=1
cd generator-jhipster
npm i
npm link
```

After that I got this error in git bash

```
$ jhipster --version
bash: jhipster: command not found
```

Then tried with windows powdershell

```
PS C:\opensource\generator-jhipster> jhipster --version
jhipster : The term 'jhipster' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ jhipster --version
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (jhipster:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

no luck.

i am using

```
PS C:\opensource\generator-jhipster> npm --version
8.19.1
PS C:\opensource\generator-jhipster> node --version
v18.9.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually from jhipster v8, we need to execute the command like

```
npx jhipster --version
```

```
PS C:\opensource\generator-jhipster> npx jhipster --version
WARNING! Since JHipster v8, the jhipster command will not use the locally installed generator-jhipster.
    If you want to execute the locally installed generator-jhipster, run: npx jhipster
7.9.3
```